# Increasing speed on plotly animation

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I created a choropleth map using plotly express's function choropleth() Code is below.

```
fig = px.choropleth(df_countrydate, 
                    locations="Country", 
                    locationmode = "country names",
                    color="Confirmed", 
                    hover_name="Country", 
                    animation_frame="Date",
                    color_continuous_scale="Reds"
                   )
fig.update_layout(
    title_text = 'Global Spread of Coronavirus',
    title_x = 0.5,
    geo=dict(
        showframe = False,
        showcoastlines = False,
    ))

iplot(fig)
```

It's a dynamic map and I was wondering if there was anyway I could speed up the transitions from one date to the next when I hit play.

Comment: Are you able to share the data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change these 2 parameters in your plot:

```
    fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 30
    fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 5
```

Time is in milliseconds

I got the answer from the code of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCUrpCpGZ5o&t=1156s&ab_channel=CharmingData
You can find the whole code here: https://github.com/Coding-with-Adam/Dash-by-Plotly/blob/master/Plotly_Graphs/Animated_Scatter/gender_ineq.py

I also found that the resolution of the map (110 vs 50) really impacts the refresh rate of the animation. In my project displaying the evolution of a variable was more relevant than the detail, since my intention was presenting the change over time of said variable. I considered it was less likely for users to try to zoom in the map, so I decided to use the lower resolution map (1:110m vs 1:50m):

```
fig.update_geos(projection_type="equirectangular", visible=True, resolution=110)
```

All those options combined resulted in a fast and smooth animation for my map after lowering the frame and animation duration.
With resolution=50, I couldn't see any effect when changing the duration values.