# Play frames back in real time based on animation_frame

Tags: python, plotly

I have a simple figure like this:

```py
fig = px.scatter(
    x=list(map(lambda x: x["posX"], data["events"])),
    y=list(map(lambda x: x["posY"], data["events"])),
    range_x=[0, data["width"]],
    range_y=[0, data["height"]],
    animation_frame=list(map(lambda x: x["timestamp"], data["events"]))
)

for movement in data["events"]:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            mode="markers",
            x=[movement["posX"]],
            y=[movement["posY"]],
            marker=dict(
                size=1,
                opacity=0.5,
                line=dict(
                    color="LightBlue",
                    width=8
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

using the following sample data:

```json
{
    "events": [
        {
            "posX": 478,
            "posY": 454,
            "timestamp": 16215.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 486,
            "posY": 456,
            "timestamp": 16229.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 529,
            "posY": 470,
            "timestamp": 16251.400000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 567,
            "posY": 483,
            "timestamp": 16262.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 644,
            "posY": 505,
            "timestamp": 16285.300000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 679,
            "posY": 514,
            "timestamp": 16296.400000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 783,
            "posY": 536,
            "timestamp": 16317.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 856,
            "posY": 550,
            "timestamp": 16330.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 987,
            "posY": 575,
            "timestamp": 16352.400000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 1036,
            "posY": 583,
            "timestamp": 16363.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1138,
            "posY": 599,
            "timestamp": 16385.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1183,
            "posY": 603,
            "timestamp": 16397
        },
        {
            "posX": 1219,
            "posY": 604,
            "timestamp": 16418.400000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 1230,
            "posY": 604,
            "timestamp": 16430
        },
        {
            "posX": 1235,
            "posY": 603,
            "timestamp": 16453.10000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1236,
            "posY": 602,
            "timestamp": 16465.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1237,
            "posY": 601,
            "timestamp": 16487.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1237,
            "posY": 601,
            "timestamp": 16499.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1233,
            "posY": 597,
            "timestamp": 16519.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1230,
            "posY": 595,
            "timestamp": 16531.10000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1229,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16553.300000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1229,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16577.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1230,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16587.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1230,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16598.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1230,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16632.300000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1229,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16643.900000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 1227,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16654.699999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1225,
            "posY": 593,
            "timestamp": 16666.10000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1223,
            "posY": 592,
            "timestamp": 16679
        },
        {
            "posX": 1215,
            "posY": 590,
            "timestamp": 16701.300000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1206,
            "posY": 589,
            "timestamp": 16712.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1184,
            "posY": 587,
            "timestamp": 16735.400000002235
        },
        {
            "posX": 1171,
            "posY": 585,
            "timestamp": 16746.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1148,
            "posY": 582,
            "timestamp": 16768.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1134,
            "posY": 580,
            "timestamp": 16780.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1107,
            "posY": 576,
            "timestamp": 16802.5
        },
        {
            "posX": 1093,
            "posY": 574,
            "timestamp": 16814
        },
        {
            "posX": 1069,
            "posY": 571,
            "timestamp": 16836.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1065,
            "posY": 570,
            "timestamp": 16847.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1060,
            "posY": 570,
            "timestamp": 16870.10000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1059,
            "posY": 570,
            "timestamp": 16881.699999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1057,
            "posY": 569,
            "timestamp": 16903.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1056,
            "posY": 569,
            "timestamp": 16914.699999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1053,
            "posY": 569,
            "timestamp": 16936.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1051,
            "posY": 569,
            "timestamp": 16949.10000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1048,
            "posY": 569,
            "timestamp": 16971.699999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1045,
            "posY": 568,
            "timestamp": 16982.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1038,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17005.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1035,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17016.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1032,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17038
        },
        {
            "posX": 1032,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17050.300000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1032,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17072.60000000149
        },
        {
            "posX": 1032,
            "posY": 567,
            "timestamp": 17083.800000000745
        },
        {
            "posX": 1030,
            "posY": 566,
            "timestamp": 17105.699999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1028,
            "posY": 565,
            "timestamp": 17118.199999999255
        },
        {
            "posX": 1027,
            "posY": 565,
            "timestamp": 17138.400000002235
        }
    ],
    "destination": {
        "topLeft": [
            994,
            549.5
        ],
        "bottomRight": [
            1033.71875,
            571
        ]
    },
    "width": 1440,
    "height": 728
}
```

I want to be able to replay this data in order according to `timestamp`, which is in milliseconds.

I have the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64827359/16025034):

```py
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 1
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 1
```

which updates it every millisecond. The problem is, it plays each frame every millisecond, instead of playing it back in real time based on `animation_frame` (which is the `timestamp` variable in each JSON array element).

How would I go about making it play back in real time, instead of every millisecond? `timestamp` is in milliseconds.

Comment: What does real-time playback mean? Do you mean that you want the current milliseconds to be in date/time format through?

Comment: @r-beginners "Real time" means that it waits out the correct duration between traces. Because the first one is `16215`, this means it should wait that many milliseconds before displaying the first one, then wait 14ms afterwards (`16229-16225`) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with frame duration, and also discovering that `frame` can be an array of frames from [Plotly's JavaScript documentation on animations](https://plotly.com/javascript/animations/), I ended up with this code that correctly plays the data in real time.

```py
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["frame"] = [
    {
        # duration is how long the frame remains in this state
        # including the time spent transitioning.
        "duration": data["events"][i]["timestamp"] - data["events"][i-1]["timestamp"]
    }

    for i in range(1, len(data["events"]))
]
```

From the documentation:

> The transition duration defines the amount of time spent interpolating a trace from one state to another (currently limited to scatter traces), while the frame duration defines the total time spent in that state, including time spent transitioning.

The code uses list comprehension to calculate the difference from the current timestamp and the previous one, since in my case the timestamps are incremental.